# IndexError: list assignment index out of range Python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, indexof

```
def mode(given_list):
    highest_list = []
    highest = 0
    index = 0
    for x in range(0, len(given_list)):
        occurrences = given_list.count(given_list[x])
        if occurrences > highest:
            highest = occurrences
            highest_list[0] = given_list[x]
        elif occurrences == highest:
            highest_list.append(given_list[x])
```

The code is meant to work out the mode of a given list. I do not understand where I am going wrong.

Exact Error I am receiving.

```
line 30, in mode
    highest_list[0] = given_list[x]
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have an empty list originally:

```
highest_list = []
```

And then in the loop you try to access it at index 0:

```
highest_list[0] = ...
```

It's impossible, because it's an empty list and so is not indexable at position 0.

A better way to find the mode of a list is to use a `collections.Counter` object:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> L = [1,2,3,3,4]
>>> counter = Counter(L)
>>> max(counter, key=counter.get)
3
>>> [(mode, n_occurrences)] = counter.most_common(1)
>>> mode, n_occurrences
(3, 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as getting the mode, you can just use a Counter from the collections library

```
from collections import Counter
x = [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0] #0 is the mode
g = Counter(x)
mode = max(g, key = lambda x: g[x])
```

Comment: You can use `g.get` instead of `lambda x: g[x]`.

Answer (score 0):

At that point, at the start of the loop, `highest_list` is empty, so there's no first index. You can initialize `highest_list` as `[0]` so that there is always at least one "highest value."

That said, you can accomplish this more simply as follows:

```
def mode(given_list):
    return max(set(given_list), key=given_list.count)
```

This will find the highest item in the passed `given_list`, based on each item's `count()` in it. Making a `set` first ensures that each item is only counted once.